# Displaced margins in beamer footer after MikTeX update

Tags: beamer, header-footer, vertical-alignment

I recently updated MikTeX on Windows 10, and now all my beamer slides are exported with 0 margin in the footer, so that the Author short name, short title etc is displayed all crammed up at the top of the footer. I am using CambridgeUS theme, but the problem is there in eg. Warsaw as well.

Minimal working example

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\title[short title]{title}

\author[short author name]{author names}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Something text here
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I've tried uninstalling and installing the beamer package to no avail, it looks like this when compiled:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!